# How to configure Apache httpd.conf run with strawberry perl?(perl script run with browser)

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

i want to run perl script on browser.i am using strawberry perl and i want to Apache httpd.conf configuration.help me?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives a detailed explanation on Strawberry Perl and Apache.

### Testing scenario for Strawberry 5.12

should work with:
- any 32bit perl 5.12.x (Win32)
- any 32bit Apache 2.2.x (Win32)

successfully tested with:
- strawberry-perl-5.12.1.0-beta-1 (from http://strawberryperl.com/beta/)
- httpd-2.2.15-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8m-r2.msi (from http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/binaries/win32/)
- both x86/32bit
- tested on Windows7 box.....Continued in the link below

http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/mod_perl/README-512.TXT